# Pythonic way to copy list to a sip.voidptr from QSharedMemory

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsharedmemory

I am using PyQT5 and the QSharedMemory class. I am creating a shared memory which can hold up 6 1-byte elements. To copy these elments in the shared memory array I am looping over the elments from the python list like the following snippet:

```
f = shared_mem.data()
k = f.asarray()
memtocopy = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(0,len(memtocopy)):
    k[i]  = memtocopy[i]
shared_mem.unlock()
```

Which seems very unpythonic and boilerplate-code like. I am wondering if there is a more suitable way of achieving the same result?

When using

```
k[:] = memtocopy
```

or:

```
k[:] = np.asarray(memtocopy,np.uint8)
```

It will fail with the error message:

```
TypeError: can only assign another array of unsigned char to the slice
```

The whole test code for reproducing looks like the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore 

# Create shared memory and attach it
shared_mem = QtCore.QSharedMemory()
shared_mem.setNativeKey("test")
shared_mem.create(4*6)
shared_mem.attach()


# Fill in 
shared_mem.lock()
f = shared_mem.data()
k = f.asarray()

memtocopy = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

# Loop in question
for i in range(0,len(memtocopy)):
    k[i]  = memtocopy[i]

shared_mem.unlock()



# Read out
shared_mem.lock()
f1 = shared_mem.data()
k1 = f1.asarray()
shared_mem.unlock()

# Test results
if k1[0] == memtocopy[0]:
    print("success!")
else:
    print("fail!")
```

Comment: Why not `k[:] = memtocopy`?

Comment: This will result in TypeError: can only assign another array of unsigned char to the slice, I have edited the question to show this case, too

Comment: Then it might be a matter of figuring out what array type it wants. I'd guess `ctypes`, but perhaps it supports the buffer protocol. [PyQt's documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/QtCore/qsharedmemory.html#PyQt5-QtCore-QSharedMemory) was no help.

Comment: [`sip.voidptr.asarray`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html#sip.voidptr.asarray) is new from version 4.16.5, which explains why I didn't have it in Debian Jessie. So the array type is [`sip.array`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html#sip.array), which again happens to be documented only as far as existing.

Comment: sip [should support the buffer protocol](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/using.html#support-for-python-s-buffer-interface), so using a Python `array.array` or `bytearray` should really work. Lists of ints won't.

Comment: I expect `k1` will be referencing the shared memory, so you should read it while you're holding the lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach using [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) and [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) that reads and writes the data with a couple of one-liners
:

```
import struct
from PyQt5 import QtCore

shared_mem = QtCore.QSharedMemory()
shared_mem.setNativeKey("test")
shared_mem.create(4*6)
shared_mem.attach()

memtocopy = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

try:

    # Fill in 
    shared_mem.lock()
    shared_mem.data()[:] = memoryview(struct.pack('=6i', *memtocopy))
    shared_mem.unlock()

    # Read out
    shared_mem.lock()
    # python3
    k = memoryview(shared_mem.data()).cast('i')
    # python2
    # k = struct.unpack('=6i', memoryview(shared_mem.data()))
    shared_mem.unlock()

    if k[3] == memtocopy[3]:
        print("success!")
    else:
        print("fail!")

finally:

    shared_mem.detach()
```

Comment: I am assumg '=6i' is for copying 6 integers?

Comment: @Kev1n91. Yes - the format is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings). The `=` should ensure the memoryview cast works the same way on all platforms. Of course, if you're only targeting one platform, you can just use `6i`.

Comment: I am getting the error "memorieveiw" object has no attribute cast

Comment: @Kev1n91. That's because you've changed to python2. Obviously my answer uses python3, because that is what your original question uses. Anyway, I've added a python2 one-liner to my answer.

Comment: I haven't noticed that, I am on a docker container which is not handled by me. Sorry about that mess up

Comment: @Kev1n91. Okay, no problem. Can you please now restore the accept on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of fiddling about, I managed to produce one combination that functioned for me:

```
a = array.array('i', range(6))
f[:] = buffer(a)
b = array.array('i')
b.fromstring(buffer(f))
```

This relies on the buffer protocol for reading both ways. It is likely you can use the array directly with your `k`, and `fromstring` has been renamed to `frombytes` in later versions.

In Python 3.4, this worked:

```
a = array.array('i', range(6))
f[:] = memoryview(a).cast('B')
b = array.array('i')
b.frombytes(memoryview(f))
```

[`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) replaced `buffer`, but knew the elements were 4 bytes large, so it required an additional cast.

Comment: This won't work in python3 (which the OP seems to be using), because there is no `buffer` function (and you cannot simply replace it with `memoryview`).

Comment: I almost could - one cast was required.

Comment: what would happen if one uses integersr? frombytes wouldn't be usable at this point ?

Comment: This does use integers (`'i'` type in array). `frombytes` simply tells it to load from memory.