# (PyQt6) How can I write bytes to memory using sip.voidptr?

Tags: qt, pyqt6

I want to fill the pixel data of an empty `QVideoFrame` instance. In PySide6, the `bits(0)` method returns a memory view and I can directly modify it by slicing and assigning. But in PyQt6, `sip.voidptr` is returned instead and I can't figure out how should I deal with it!

I am not really familiar with Python C bindings. Is there any way to easily access the memory using `voidptr`? Thanks in advance!

## Edit 1

Here is a sample code.

```py
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtMultimedia

pfmt = QtMultimedia.QVideoFrameFormat.PixelFormat.Format_Y8
ffmt = QtMultimedia.QVideoFrameFormat(QtCore.QSize(1280, 1024), pfmt)
vf = QtMultimedia.QVideoFrame(ffmt)

vf.map(QtMultimedia.QVideoFrame.MapMode.ReadWrite)

# Data manipulation should come here.

vf.unmap()
```

## Edit 2

Ok, I found out that `voidptr` can be converted to an array by passing the size of the video frame.

In the comment location of the code above,

```py
>>> size = vf.bytesPerLine(0)*vf.height()
>>> vf.bits(0).asarray(size)
PyQt6.sip.array(unsigned char, 1310720)
```

Modifying a single pixel works fine.

```py
>>> arr = vf.bits(0).asarray(vf.bytesPerLine(0)*vf.height())
>>> arr[0]
0
>>> arr[0] = 255
>>> arr[0]
255
```

But assigning the bytes to `sip.array` raised error.

```py
>>> data = bytes(255 for _ in range(size))
>>> arr[:] = data
TypeError: can only assign another array of unsigned char to the slice
```

Answers in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180788/11501976) raised same error.

Comment: You could try to follow a procedure similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360009/how-can-access-to-pixel-data-with-pyqt-qimage-scanline). I suppose that the size has to be set using [`QVideoFrame.mappedBytes()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvideoframe.html#mappedBytes).

Comment: I don't have lot of experience with SIP and memory access, but I believe it's possible that SIP arrays don't properly implement the `slice` argument of `__getitem__()`, and revert to the default behavior that just maps values as integers. I'd suggest you to write to the [PyQt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt), providing a valid [mre].

Comment: @musicamante Setting the size of `voidptr` did the trick. No `asarray()` required. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @musicamante I managed to find the solution. It seems that `voidptr` can be directly accessed to write the bytes, provided that its size is known. `QVideoFrame.bits()` returns `voidptr` with unknown size (perhaps it is a bug of PyQt) so I had to manually set the size from `QVideoFrame.mappedBytes`.

Here is the full code:

```py
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtMultimedia

pfmt = QtMultimedia.QVideoFrameFormat.PixelFormat.Format_Y8
ffmt = QtMultimedia.QVideoFrameFormat(QtCore.QSize(1280, 1024), pfmt)
vf = QtMultimedia.QVideoFrame(ffmt)

vf.map(QtMultimedia.QVideoFrame.MapMode.ReadWrite)

ptr = frame.bits(0)
ptr.setsize(frame.mappedBytes(0))
ptr[:] = bytes(255 for _ in range(size))

vf.unmap()
```