# Improving performance of animated shape drawing using Python Qt5 QPainter

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5

In my Qt5 application I need to draw several animated custom shapes on a widget (several polygons, icons, etc). Currently this results in lots of QPoints being instantiated every paint cycle, since i need to update every point of every QPolygon in every time frame. I'm wondering whether there is a less ugly and more performant/direct way to do this. I already have all my points given in a single memory block. To me it makes no sense in splitting it up and into single QPoint objects.

My pseudo implementation currently looks like this:

1. Compute all points and store as rows in numpy array
2. In a loop, copy all points from numpy array to QPoint instances one by one
3. Pass all QPoints to QPolygon
4. Draw polygon using QPainter

Is there any better approach/implementation possible in PyQt5?

What i'd like to have is those ugly steps 2 and 3 eliminated:

1. Compute all points (lots of algebra, hence this is done in numpy)
2. Pass memory block of numpy array to QPolygon and define how it has to be interpreted
3. Draw polygon

Comment: Sooner or later, you'll be using QPoints anyway (either explicitly or internally created by Qt). Unfortunately, without seeing what your code actually does it's impossible to give you any advice, so please provide a valid [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a somewhat simple solution which eliminates the loop to copy all the points one by one. The trick is to pre-allocate the QPolygon, get its sip.voidptr and interpret it as numpy array. Here's an example:

```
poly = QPolygonF([QPointF(10, 10)] * 3)
src = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

ptr = poly.data()
ptr.setsize(8 * poly.size() * 2)

dest = np.frombuffer(ptr)
dest[:] = src
```

Unfortunately, I have to set the size of ptr manually, but at least I can use this approach to write the computation results directly into the polygons memory (does anyone know how to get the byte size of the data referenced by QPolygon?).

[Here's the post where I found the necessary hint with the sip.voidptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75311549/pyqt6-how-can-i-write-bytes-to-memory-using-sip-voidptr)